# Determine if the mouse made a complete circle around a point

Tags: actionscript, rotation, mouse, point

I have a game I am working on. I am trying to detect if the mouse has made a complete 360 degree rotation around a certain point. I am completely struggling with the logic though. The full rotation can be forwards or backwards from a dynamic start point.

What I have to work with now:

So any properties can be added and to start with I have the current angle relative to the point (a sword.)

so

angleNow =

and

sword. any properties can be added. I was messing around with properties like the direction the angle was moving in, the start angle, etc...

I would post code but it is kind of obscure and completely incorrect.

Can anyone help me out with this? Pseudo code would be good. Hopefully this makes  some sense... well code

```
    if (sword.motionDirection == Const.DIRECTION_POSITIVE) {

        if (rotateAngle >= sword.motionCurrent) { trace("GOOD" + gameCounter);
            sword.motionCurrent = rotateAngle; // update the current
        }
        else { // switch directions
            trace("SWITCH" + gameCounter);
            sword.motionCurrent = rotateAngle; sword.motionDirection = Const.DIRECTION_NEGATIVE; sword.motionStart = rotateAngle;
        }
    }
```

rotateAngle is the angle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution is to divide the stage based on the point to circle and the point where the mouse begins.

You can calculate a line through the mouse and the point, as well as a perpendicular line in order to form quadrants of the stage.

In this image, the mouse is a square and the point is a point.  You can tell which direction the mouse moves by finding out which quadrant it enters.  Once the mouse has entered each quadrant in the correct order (1-4 or 4-1), you know that the moment the mouse enters the 1st quadrant it entered, it will have completed a full circle.

Example:

The mouse enters quadrant one (Q1) first then enters Q2, Q3, and then Q4.  At this point, only by entering Q1 again will the mouse have passed the line it started on and completed a full circle.

[image: Image of Mouse, Point, and quadrants]

```
//Import mouse events
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
//on whatever event you want throw function to check_for_circle

    var bound_Q1:Array = [0,90];
    var bound_Q2:Array = [90,180];
    var bound_Q3:Array = [180,270];
    var bound_Q4:Array = [270,0];
    var Q1 = false;
    var Q2 = false;
    var Q3 = false;
    var Q4 = false;


function check_for_circle(event:MouseEvent){
  //Calculate angle bounds for each Quadrant
  //add logic to make sure degrees wrap at 360
  bound_Q1[0]=//mouse start degree;
  bound_Q1[1]=bound_Q1[0]+90;
  bound_Q2[0]=bound_Q1[1];
  bound_Q2[1]=bound_Q2[0]+90;
  bound_Q3[0]=bound_Q2[1];
  bound_Q3[1]=bound_Q3[0]+90;
  bound_Q4[0]=bound_Q3[1];
  bound_Q4[1]=bound_Q1[0];
}

if(rotateAngle>bound_Q1[0] && rotateAngle<bound_Q1[1]/*mouse is in Q1*/){
  if(Q1 && Q2 && Q3 && Q4){
    //full circle!
  }else if(Q1 && Q2){
    //This means we turned around
    Q4=false;
    Q3=false;
    Q2=false;
  }
  //we are in Q1
  Q1=true;
}

if(rotateAngle>bound_Q2[0] && rotateAngle<bound_Q2[1]/*mouse is in Q2*/){
  if(Q1 && Q2 && Q3 && Q4){
    //we started at Q4 and turned around
    Q1=false;
  }else if(Q1 && Q2 && Q3){
    //We started at Q1 and turned around
    Q3=false;
    Q4=false;
  }
  //we are in Q2
  Q2=true;
}

if(rotateAngle>bound_Q3[0] && rotateAngle<bound_Q3[1]/*mouse is in Q3*/){
  if(Q1 && Q2 && Q3 && Q4){
    //we started at Q1 and turned around
    Q4=false;
  }else if(Q4 && Q2 && Q3){
    //We started at Q4 and turned around
    Q2=false;
    Q1=false;
  }
  //we are in Q3
  Q3=true;
}
if(rotateAngle>bound_Q4[0] && rotateAngle<bound_Q4[1]/*mouse is in Q4*/){
  if(Q1 && Q2 && Q3 && Q4){
    //full circle!
  }else if(Q4 && Q3){
    //This means we turned around
    Q1=false;
    Q3=false;
    Q2=false;
  }
  //we are in Q4
  Q4=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A mouse has made a complete circle around a point if it begins and ends in the same place.  If we follow this definition exactly, it can cause some problems in a game because then players would not need to complete the circle to throw any circle completion events.

However if you do a hit-test with the mouse coordinates where the mouse begins, where it exits in a certain direction, and when it enters in a certain direction, you will be able to avoid such problems.

Since that was a jumble of words that made little to no sense, I have a brightly colored diagram for you below.

Let's pretend two things.  First, that the blue dot is the point we wish to circumscribe. And second, that we want to only do our circle test after we have clicked.

When we click on a certain point around our blue dot, a hit-test area appears.  It is made up of three individual testable areas, let's call them `left_exit` (visible as the lower green element), `right_exit`(visible as the upper green element), and `center` (visible as the red element).

The hit-test area appears so that `center` is under the mouse and stretches all the way from the edge of the Stage to the blue dot.

While the mouse remains in `center`, nothing occurs.

However, when the mouse moves out of center there are three possible occurences:

1. The mouse failed to move in a circular fashion and did not hit either green areas

   In this case, we know that the mouse failed to go in a circle and we can cancel the hit test.
2. The mouse moved to the upper green element `right_exit`.

   In this case we know that the mouse is now moving in a specific direction and in order to save that direction we can set a boolean value (possibly called `hit_right`) to true.
3. The mouse moved to the lower green element `left_exit`.

   In this case we also know that the mouse is moving in a specific direction and we can save that direction by setting a boolean value (possibly called `hit_left`) to true.

In cases 2 and 3 there are two possible options:

1. The mouse returns to the red element `center`.

   In which case they are no longer moving in a specific direction and thus we can set certain boolean values to false.
2. The mouse exits the element and goes to the opposite green element.

   In which case a circle is almost complete. and we can set the other boolean value to true.

After case 2, there are two possible options:

1. The mouse leaves this green element in the wrong direction.

   Meaning a circle is still not complete.
2. The mouse enters the red element `center`.

   Meaning we have completed a circle.

[image: Mouse Hit Test Circle]

```
//Import mouse events
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
//on mouse event MOUSE_DOWN throw function check_for_circle
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, check_for_circle);

    var hit_right = false;
    var hit_left = false;

function check_for_circle(event:MouseEvent){
  //draw invisible hit-test
  //make sure that center forms a line from the 
  //point, through the mouse, and to the edge of the stage
}

right_exit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, check_right);
left_exit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, check_left);
center.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, check_center);
//add MOUSE_OUT checks as well
//and if you are scared that people will try to cheat, 
//add a MOUSE_LEAVE function to the stage

function check_right(event:MouseEvent){
  hit_right = true;
}
function check_left(event:MouseEvent){
  hit_left = true;
}
function check_center(event:MouseEvent){
  if(hit_left && hit_right){
    //yay it worked!
  }
  else{
  hit_left = false;
  hit_right = false;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I took a crack at it and had some trouble following it. I think I get the main idea, like having movieclips around the point, and make sure the mouse hittests them in the correct order.

Though, I am looking for a possible simple solution. I still have some flaws in the logic, but it works correctly for at least the positive direction. I also got rid of a dynamic "start point," to simplify it.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out how to post code, but here is unformmated:

` if (rotateAngle > lastAngle) lastAngle = rotateAngle;
 else if (rotateAngle < lastAngle) { 
  if (lastAngle > 350 && rotateAngle >= 0) {
   trace("PossibleCircle&Reset" + count); 
   lastAngle = 0; 
  }
 }
 else { 
  trace("elsed"); 
 }
`

it works if you move around in a positive direction, but if you move backwards it traces possiblecircle every mouse movement.

the angle rotateAngle is relative to the point its circling, and the mouse. I'm really just trying to see if the mouse moves all around the point.

Comment: If I can't get it to work this way, I will take another look at your way, thanks for the thorough example.

Comment: My mistake, the way I was trying to do it jumped numbers on the angles so it really could not tell if it went around in a circle. So, thanks, I will go with your method.

Comment: Big test-areas are the way to go because angles will never be perfect in a fps environment.  If you want to keep the angle measurement logic you had, check out the other answer.